# Chrome 96 - How to tell if a website is using an EV SSL certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

When using Chrome 96, how do I tell if an SSL certificate is an EV SSL certificate?  Here's what Chrome does display:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EV certificates have [a specific policy OID](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/EV_Processing_for_CAs) in their "Certificate Policies" extension.

These policy OIDs vary by CA (e.g. for Entrust it's `2.16.840.1.114028.10.1.2`, meanwhile for DigiCert it's `2.16.840.1.114412.2.1`) as they reference policy documents published by each issuing CA. There *is* a common "CA/B Forum EV Guidelines" policy OID `2.23.140.1.1` which may be used alongside or in addition to CA-specific policies, but it's not actually guaranteed to be present.

As CAs must be pre-approved to issue EV certificates, browsers recognize them by having a list of specific CAs and their respective policy OIDs; for example, here's [the Firefox list](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/security/certverifier/ExtendedValidation.cpp#90).

Your website's certificate has both the `2.16.840.1.114028.10.1.2` (Entrust) and `2.23.140.1.1` (CA/B Forum) EV policy OIDs, and its issuer is at least in Mozilla's EV-approved CA list, making it an EV certificate.

[image]

(As an additional hint, an EV certificate's "Subject" field will typically include very detailed information about the subject, such as the `serialNumber=` and `businessCategory=` fields. This doesn't automatically indicate it's an EV certificate, but is rarely if ever seen for non-EV certs.)

Comment: You stated "Your website's certificate has both the 2.16.840.1.114028.10.1.2 (Entrust) and 2.23.140.1.1 (CA/B Forum) EV policy OIDs, ..." How did you determine this?  I don't see this info in the screen captures I posted.

Comment: @mbmast: I got the domain name from your screen captures, connected to the web server, and downloaded the same certificate myself. [It has the OIDs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8eNv.png)

Comment: So it sounds like there is no way to make this determination by simply inspecting the certificate through the standard Chrome 96 user interface (as I attempted to do).  Rather, one must download the certificate and then what...?  Use some inspection tool that is not part of Chrome?

Comment: In the linked screenshot, I used literally the same inspection tool that you used, i.e. the Windows "Certificate information" popup that Chrome opens.

Comment: Ah! On the General tab, not the Details tab.  Got it.

Comment: It is not the General tab. It is the bottom half of the Details tab, after you select the correct extension in the top half.